# Entity framework insert not getting reflected in database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4.0 with MySQL.

This is my code:

```
using (Entities myEntities = new Entities(dataAccess.GetConnectionString()))
{
    student sObj = new student();
    sObj.id = stud.id;
    sObj.rollNo = stud.rno;
    sObj.key = (Int64)stud.key;
    myEntities.student.AddObject(sObj);
    myEntities.SaveChanges();

    long maxId = (from f in myEntities.student select f.id).Max();
    logger.Info("maxId: " + maxId);
}
```

I'm getting new `maxId` every time, niot getting any errors. But when I see database, no rows getting added. And this is happening only with this table. Working fine for all other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark it modified

```
EntityState.Modified
```